# Get the returned value of Stored Procedure in EF6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in my SQL Server database which I use as a concurrency control.

For example :

```
IF row is deleted concurrently 
   RETURN 0
ELSE IF row is edited concurrently 
   RETURN -1
ELSE 
   RETURN 1
```

Using C# when I do:

```
int i = myContext.SP(params);
```

it seems that the stored procedure returns only 0 and 1 and it never returns the -1 value (I get the -1 when I run the stored procedure in SQL Server Management Studio so it is fine).

I think that this may not be proper way to get the returned value of the stored procedure. How could this be done ?

Comment: @user2864740: I mean it only returns 0 and 1 no matter what the returned value is

Comment: I believe it's not possible to do this with EF

Comment: @DavidG: if that's true, it's so sad

Comment: Are params a collection of `SqlParameter`?

Comment: @PierreOverFlow Well EF is an ORM, not a full replacement for SQL/ADO/etc.

Comment: @CamBruce: It doesn't matter, the stored procedure is fine, the value is either updated or not. when updated successfully no matter what number is there (like true false), I get the 1, else 0. And no, they are not SqlParaemeters, they are C# properties

Comment: It does matter, because to get a return value, you have to use a use a `SqlParameter` and set `SqlParameter.Direction =  ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;` The way you are doing it is incorrect.

Comment: @CamBruce this is entity framework, not ADO

Comment: @CamBruce: I'm using Entity Framework!

Comment: I'm well aware of that. The Entity Framework is just a layer on top of ADO.NET. Please answer my question.

Comment: The params will simply be the values the Sp takes, e.g int/string/datetime/etc values.

Comment: What does `SP` look like?

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil: The SP is fine, this is related to Entity Framework, not the SQL code.

Comment: I'm asking what the `SP` method looks like so I can see how you're calling the stored proc.

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil: I'm calling it like `var Result = Context.SP(ID, Name, Adress, etc);`

Comment: But what happens **inside** of the method?

Comment: @Smith.h.Neil: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg699321.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An Entity Framework question necessitates an Entity Framework solution. In this situation I just realized that I can also do this:

```
 //Run the SP
 Context.SP(params...,ID, Version);
 //Check the result 
 //Concurrently Deleted
 var C_Deleted = Context.Table.Where(x=> x.ID.Equals(ID)).Count() <= 0;
 //Concurrently Edited
 var C_Edited = (from x in Context.Table
                where x.ID.Equals(ID)
                && 
                x.Version == Version
                select x).Count() <= 0;
```